# Create new DataFrame and fill in its columns without using pandas functions, but with for/while loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop

I have the [image: original DataFrame] named `movies_converted`. And I am to create a new empty DataFrame `director_rating` with columns `Director` and `Average IMDB Rating` and fill in `Director` with values from the original column with the same name and fill in `Average IMDB Rating` with average values in given category from original `IMDB Rating`. Filling in columns must be without using pandas functions, but with using for and while loops. Please, show me how to do it

Comment: Are you aware that there are more efficient techniques than `for/while` to perform operations with dataframes?

Comment: I guessed. But it's my university homework so I must follow directions...

Comment: You should try reading about `.iterrows`, `loc`, and `for/while` loops in general. Try youtube and google, there are lots of easy-to-follow tutorials.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use:

```
df.groupby("Director")["IMDB Rating"].mean()
```

But if you were to do it in a looped format without using pandas functions you can do it this way. You just loop through each unique director, and create two arrays saving:

1. the sum of ratings, divided by the number of movies (i.e. the average rating).
2. the name of the director

Then use these two arrays and create a new pandas dataframe.

```
directors_unique = []

for i in movies_converted.Director:
    if i not in directors_unique:
        directors_unique.append(i)

list_directors = []
list_ratings = []
for director in directors_unique:
    list_directors.append(director)
    list_ratings.append(sum(movies_converted[movies_converted["Director"] == director]["IMDB Rating"])/len(movies_converted[movies_converted["Director"] == director]))
    director_rating = pd.DataFrame({"Director":list_directors, "Average IMDB Rating":list_ratings})
```

Comment: Though `Series.unique()` is still a pandas function :p

Comment: I did this and I get an error https://ibb.co/9H12jjq I don't understand

Comment: @ALollz Good call out. Updated... Never really considered doing this type of activity this way

Comment: I see, your naming is just different. Keep in mind what each variable is named. I have updated the code to fit what you need, more or less.

Comment: Ah I just meant it in fun. It's always hard to know where the line is drawn on these unproductive (personal opinion) homework problems. As an aside, you might get away with just `for director in set(movies_converted.Director):` At least `set` is standard :p

Comment: @sdhaus sorry for annoying, but what is wrong now? now it doesn't give any output at all https://ibb.co/tc7mZKh

Comment: @DianaPavlova No output seems strange. What happens if you run directors_rating in a different cell?

Comment: @sdhaus hmm in this case I think it works properly: https://ibb.co/SxR3W1P

Comment: @DianaPavlova right, thats because you are trying to preview the dataframe within the loop, which doesn't pretty print. The above cell would work if you un-indented the final line (directors_rating)